# How to calculate that integral without any error messages?

Tags: numerical-integration

My attempts

```
 NIntegrate[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

and

```
NIntegrate[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

and

```
NIntegrate[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
```

perform

```
(*112.397602019569 - 0.0476573486479931 I*)
```

and the error communication

> NIntegrate::ncvb:NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in w near {w}={169.666666666667}.NIntegrate obtained 112.397602019569-0.0476573486479931 I and 3.53579276891817`15. for the integral and error estimates.

as a bonus.

In order to get rid of error messages, the `Quiet` command is not taken into account.

Comment: `Integrate ` says, this integral does not converge.

Comment: Most likely, you are using `WorkingPrecision` wrong. Why do you set the working precision to be 15?

Comment: @Akku: Thank you. Can that statement be based? Every command has its limitations.

Comment: @Anton Antonov: Can you kindly suggest a better option?

Comment: @Akku 14: The command `Integrate[
 Evaluate[ComplexExpand[
   Re[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I)]]], {w, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}]` is running for long time without any error communication.

Comment: @Akku 14: The same with `Integrate[
 Evaluate[ComplexExpand[
   Im[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I)]]], {w, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}]` .

Answer (score 1):

First note that the result of the Integral must be real since

$(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{8^{2+i w}}{2+i w}\zeta (i w+2)^2 \, dw)^\ast = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{8^{2-i w}}{2-i w}\zeta (-i w+2)^2 \, dw = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{8^{2+i w'}}{2+i w'}\zeta (i w'+2)^2 \, dw' $

where $w' = -w$. The integrand is highly oscillatory and decreases fast so there is not much to gain by specifying the limits at $\infty$. You can do it without errors by increasing the working precision and specifying a finite numerical integration limit as follow:

```
Int[W_] := 
  NIntegrate[Re[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I)], {w, -W, W}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
Table[{W, Int[W]}, {W, 0, 200, 10}]
ListLinePlot[%, Mesh -> Full, PlotRange -> Full]
```

which yields the following results without error messages

```
{{0, 0}, {10, 117.644687513319946046802879277}, {20, 
  114.575303504772377060321078067}, ... 
  113.956032525809081682569215295}, {180, 
  112.921219819275271019140358492}, {190, 
  112.131832550130353341971791461}, {200, 
  112.536621410476756643360381626}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your work. This is not it.

Comment: "the Integral must be real" - by this reasoning, it means that we can consider the integrand `(32 (2^(-3 I w) (2 + I w) Zeta[2 - I w]^2 + 2^(3 I w) (2 - I w) Zeta[2 + I w]^2))/(4 + w^2)`.

Comment: @J.M. : Thank you. Can you suggest what I should do next?

Comment: @user, you haven't "based" your (implied) claim that this is a convergent integral, so I haven't done anything further.

Comment: @Omrie Ovdat: Your statement "the result of the Integral must be real since... "  assumes the integral is convergent (That may not be correct.) ot its principal value.

Comment: @user64494: Indeed. The statement is valid for any integration interval [-W,W] symmetric around 0.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer on my own (It seems the integral of the real part of the integrand converges.)

```
NIntegrate[Evaluate[ComplexExpand[ Re[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I)]]],
{w, -Infinity,Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
(*110.677985578146*)
```

Addition.

```
NIntegrate[Evaluate[ComplexExpand[Im[Zeta[2 + w*I]^2*8^(2 + w*I)/(2 + w*I)]]], 
{w, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
(*32.6314986099761388250389849791092223455806688267066202788888718292899\
6103218885341303274331595001435*)
```